# Access elements of a comma separated list with tuples in Python

Tags: python, loops, csv, tuples

I have a .csv file that when opened in TextEdit looks like this:

[image]

I need my code to add each line to a list/tuple so then I can access each element.

For example:

I want to be able to loop through the entire .csv file and print just the country names.

What would be the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes, multiple things. I tried putting each line into a list, then converting to a tuple....nothing was working, was too embarrassed to post what I had.

Comment: for your own sake to avoid getting downvotes post your attempts, don't worry about what people think of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that you mean for each line, a `tuple` should store that line's value for each field:

```
lines = [tuple(row) for row in csv.reader(yourfile)]
```

You could then access just the country names by indexing the tuples:

```
for t in lines:
    print(t[1])
```

Comment: Not sure what the point is of the unpacking and repacking. Why not just `tuple(row) for row in csv.reader`

Comment: @DanielRoseman It did feel a bit strange when I was typing it, I don't know why I didn't notice. Thanks, I'll edit.

Comment: @PhilipMcQuitty I'm glad I could help. Don't forget to accept the answer when you can to show that the issue is closed.

Comment: if you just want to print the 2nd column, awk provides a shorter solution. Type the following in your shell: awk -F ',' '{print $2}' countries.csv